# how to create a pay roll in which I can add employees without using an array?

Tags: java

Here is the description of my assignment

"Implement a class called Employee. An employee has a name and gets a salary.  Every pay period each employee gets an additional amount in bonus.

In your solution, include a constructor that accepts the name and salary of an employee. Provide a mutator method that accepts the bonus amount and adds it to the salary. Provide necessary accessor methods to return the name, the salary before the bonus was applied, the bonus, and the salary after the bonus has been applied."

I have all of that done except that when I try to add another employee it just overwrites the variable and prints only the last employee added.

Heres my code:

```
    package employeetester;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTester {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Employee = "";
        String Continue;
        String printChart;
        double salary = 0;
        double bonus = 0; 
        double totalSalary = 0;


        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        EmployeePayRoll epr = new EmployeePayRoll(Employee, salary);

        System.out.print("Would you like to add an employee to the pay roll? ");
          Continue = user_input.next();

        while (Continue.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || Continue.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){

            System.out.println("What is the name of the employee?");
            Employee = user_input.next();
            epr.Employee(Employee);

            System.out.println("\nWhat is the salary of " + Employee + "? ");
            salary = user_input.nextDouble();
            epr.salary(salary);

            System.out.println("\nWhat is the bonus of " + Employee + "? ");
            bonus = user_input.nextDouble();
            epr.bonus(bonus);

            System.out.print("Would you like to add an employee to the pay roll? ");
            Continue = user_input.next();


            }

        System.out.println("\nWould you like to print out the pay roll chart? ");
            printChart = user_input.next();

            if (printChart.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || printChart.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){

                //EmployeePayRoll epr = new EmployeePayRoll(Employee, salary);
                epr.totalSalary(bonus);
                epr.printChart();
        }




    }

}
```

Here's the second part

```
package employeetester;


public class EmployeePayRoll {
    private String Employee;
    private double Salary;
    private double bonus;
    private double TotalSalary;

    public EmployeePayRoll (String Employee, double salary){

    this.Employee = Employee;
    this.Salary = salary;

}
    public void Employee(String emp){
        Employee = emp;
    }

    public void salary(double slry){
        Salary = slry;
    }

    public void bonus(double bnus){
        bonus = bnus;
    }

    public double totalSalary(double bonus){

        this.bonus = bonus;
        double totalSalary = Salary + bonus;
        this.TotalSalary = totalSalary;
        return totalSalary;
    }

    public void printChart(){

    System.out.println("\nPayRoll");
    System.out.println("-------- EMPLOYEE --------");
    System.out.println("Name:   \t" + Employee);
    System.out.println("Salary: \t" + Salary);
    System.out.println("Bonus:  \t" + bonus);
    System.out.println("Total:  \t" + TotalSalary);
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

how do I print out every employee added? the only thing I can think of is using an arraylist but we're not allowed to use that.

Comment: You need some kind of array or Collection to store multiple instances of the same type.

Comment: Go for [Collections](http://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java) in java.

Comment: Just as a side note, I would avoid using the word "Continue" as a name for a String. "continue" is actually a keyword in Java that is used with loops. The bottom of [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) explains it.